# Need help interfacing an ADC with a pressure transducer

Tags: sensor, adc, pressure

I am trying to connect a pressure transducer which gives a 4- 20mA current output to an ADC which I believe can only take voltage inputs. How will I be able to read a current output from the ADC? Do I need to change the way it is connected or do I need to purchase a new ADC or a sensor? Any advice would be appreciated.

Link to ADC used: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7606B.pdf

Link to pressure sensor used: https://www.pmc1.com/Customer-Content/www/Products/Files/ATM.1st.T.705a.pdf

Comment: You need some sort of current to voltage converter. The simplest form is a resistor.

Comment: V = I*R, you should be able to figure out the size resistor you need from that. Just place the resistor across the current source.

Comment: @LongPham Thanks, I was thinking the same, but I was a little confused about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 250 ohm resistor will give you 1~5V which you can low pass filter, clamp, and feed to your ADC. Subtract the 1V off digitally and scale to your engineering units as applicable.

The pressure sensor will need a supply of at least 14V with 24VDC being more-or-less standard.